# Autofocus SearchBar didn't work on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I use `React Native Element's` `SearchBar` component for my app.

I set the `autoFocus = {true}`.

It works fine on `iOS`, but not on `Android`.

Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here the working code sample.

```
// imports
....
....

class Abc extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.searchBar = true; // Manual Method
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <SearchBar
          autoFocus // Automatic Method
          ref={(searchBar) = { this.searchBar = searchBar; }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Your approach is correct. I have given the manual method but I suggest you go with your method. Also make sure you have passed the autoFocus prop to your `<TextInput />` wrapped inside your SearchBar component.

Eg:

```
const SearchBar = (props) => {
 const { prop1, prop2, ...txtIpProps } = props;
 return (
  <SearchBar>
    <TextInput {...txtInpProps}/>
  </SearchBar>
 )
};
```